# How to select last rows where cell is empty

Tags: mysql

I have to fetch all the rows from the end of the table where `val IS NULL` but only until a NOT NULL is found.
From this simplified table:

```
+----+------+
| id | val  |
+----+------+
|  1 | 13   |
|  2 | 15   |
|  3 | NULL |
|  4 | 66   |
|  5 | NULL |
|  6 | NULL |
+----+------+
```

I need these rows:

```
+----+------+
| id | val  |
+----+------+
|  5 | NULL |
|  6 | NULL |
+----+------+
```

So far I didn't even find any similar question except for retrieving the last element with NULL but it's not something I'm looking for.

I appreciate any help and suggestion to look up.

Comment: What if the last row of the table (row with highest `id` value) is not `null` ?

Comment: _So far I didn't even find any similar question_ But did you try and write a query to do this yet?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya if not null then returns empty array.

Comment: @RiggsFolly limiting is not an option because who knows how many NULL values at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @Tim Biegeleisen ,  but I think testing something exists is more digestible

```
select * 
from t
where id > (select max(id) from t where val is not null) and    
        exists (select 1 from t where id = (select max(id) from t) and val is null);

+------+------+
| id   | val  |
+------+------+
|    5 | NULL |
|    6 | NULL |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And with 6 having a value
drop table if exists t;
create table t
( id int,  val int);
insert into t values
(  1 , 13   ),
(  2 , 15   ),
(  3 , NULL ),
(  4 , 66   ),
(  5 , NULL ),
(  6 , 10 );

```
select * 
    from t
    where id > (select max(id) from t where val is not null) and    
            exists (select 1 from t where id = (select max(id) from t) and val is null);
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

as expected.

Comment: Why do you need the `exists` clause at all? If x is the maximum id for which val is not null, then any id greater than x if it exists will have a val of not null. It will be retrieved or not depending on whether it exits or not plain and simple. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

We can try the following approach:

```
SELECT id, val
FROM yourTable
WHERE id > (SELECT MIN(id) FROM yourTable t1
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                              WHERE t2.id > t1.id AND t2.val IS NOT NULL));
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

`SELECT *
FROM anyTable
WHERE id > (
SELECT id
FROM anyTable
WHERE val IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1)`

Comment: Simple answer, but I think it is missing the edge case when you don't have any record with `not null` values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Like this:

```
SELECT id, val
FROM table_name
WHERE val IS NULL
AND 
id > (
       SELECT id
       FROM table_name
       WHERE val IS NOT NULL
       ORDER BY id DESC
       LIMIT 1
      )
```